# Accessing the highest and lowest values that can be represented in numeric type T, a template parameter

Tags: c++, c++11

This should work, I think

```
template<typename T>
class MyClass {
    // ...
    static constexpr T minT = std::numeric_limits<T>::has_infinity
                            ? -std::numeric_limits<T>::infinity() 
                            : std::numeric_limits<T>::lowest();
    static constexpr T maxT = std::numeric_limits<T>::has_infinity 
                            ? std::numeric_limits<T>::infinity() 
                            : std::numeric_limits<T>::max();
}
```

but I was wondering whether I am missing a simpler way.

Comment: You mean simpler in terms of syntax or logic? The logic seems as minimal as it can be, IMO, but the syntax could be simplified a bit with a `using limits = std::numeric_limits<T>`.

Comment: @GregorMcGregor I thought there was maybe just one call to make.